# Azure batch start task exceeds the autoScaleEvaluationInterval

Tags: java, azure, azure-batch

I am working on Azure batch and facing an issue. I have configured a start task on my pool with wait for success as true as the start task should complete before starting the job task.

I also want to set the autoscale formula on my pool. I want to set the `autoScaleEvaluationInterval` period to be `10 mins`. But every time start task takes more than `10 mins` and autoscale formula starts deleting the pool node.

I have tried to set the `withAutoScaleEvaluationInterval` to be `30 minutes` at the time of pool creation and then when the pool is running i have tried to change it back to `10 mins`.

But this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that you are following some tips mentioned in the documentation here `:)`

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-automatic-scaling

Please take a note of `$NodeDeallocationOption` out of 4 eligible options you can try using, The value: **`taskcompletion`** -- `Waits for currently running tasks to finish and then removes the node from the pool.`